# PGFPlots - Using "smooth" doesnt render smooth curves, but "samples" doesnt work either

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, smooth

I'm using PGFPlots to generate graphs of functions. I use `smooth` to smooth out the curve, but it isn't smooth enough. So I tried increasing the `samples` option. The problem is, I can go all the way to `samples=9000` yet the graph won't draw until the end. Here are some pictures:

*Using just `smooth`*:

[image]

*Using `smooth` and `samples=10`*:

[image]

*Using `smooth` and `samples=950`*:

[image]

*Using `smooth` and `samples=2950`*:

[image]

As can be seen, using just `smooth` yields a lumpy picture, whereas using high `samples` along with `smooth` gives a great curve, but doesn't go up to the x-axis, as it should, and using higher`samples` values seems to give diminishing returns.

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mmm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 1.7]
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xmin=0,xmax=4,
            ymin=0,ymax=12,
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            axis line style=->,
            ticks=none,
        ]
        % The line below is the important one
        \addplot[name path = c, color=blue, domain=0:4, samples=950, smooth]{x^2 * (9 - x^2)^0.5};
        \addplot[name path = a, domain=0:4]{0};
        \addplot [
            thick,
            color=blue,
            fill=blue,
            fill opacity=0.05
        ]
        fill between[
            of=a and c,
        ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm adding the code to highlight under the graph where you can see how the colored area acts weird because it might be useful to you to see the strange behavior of the curve when samples are used.

Is there any way to fix this, i.e. get a smooth curve without this happening?

Comment: I think the problem is that your function is only defined between 0 and 3.

Comment: The function `x^2 * (9 - x^2)^0.5` is not defined for `|x|>3`. So use `domain=0:3`, then a small number of samples suffices. Also, **never** use `scale` in a `tikz picture` that contains an `axis`, rather set the `width` and `height` of the axis.

Comment: @user238301 Yes. But why does ```samples``` not reach ```x = 3```? Whereas smooth does?

Comment: `smooth` means that the segments are Bezier curves as opposed to straight lines, and if you choose the samples to be `4n+1` with any integer `n>1` you will "hit" 3 in a domain `0:4` but really you should choose `domain=0:3`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it seems that using 250 samples is the best number, but using more or less gives the same issue as posted ... anyway, as to the axis issue, the diagram being accurate doesn't matter as much as the general shape of it. Not stretching the x axis gives me a very tall plot. If you want to post as an answer, I can tick this question off.